# List all values in a column in the order of another column and change the output for one of the values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table called `fruits` with fields `fruit_id`, `fruit_name`. I want to output names of all the fruits in the table in the order of the fruit_id, but for "water melon" I just want to output "melon". For all other fruits, I want to output the the entire fruit name as it is in the table.

For example, if I have this data in the table:

```
fruit_id | fruit_name
---------|-----------
1        | apple
2        | guava
3        | yellow mango
4        | water melon
5        | cacao
6        | coconut
7        | green mango
```

I want to output:

```
apple
guava
yellow mango
melon
cacao
coconut
green mango
```

How can you obtain such output?

I tried

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM fruits
WHERE fruit_name
NOT IN 
(
 'apple',
 'guava',
 'yellow mango',
 'water melon',
 'cacao',
 'coconut',
 'green mango'
) 
ORDER BY fruit_name;
```

Comment: SELECT "apple guava yellow mango melon cacao coconut green mango";

Comment: And simple knowledge is helpful too. https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html

Comment: 'Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.'

Comment: I guess I did not explain it well. Assuming you don't know all the contents inside "fruits" table. You only know that there is a "water melon". How can you obtain such output? my bad on english

Comment: I've read this over several times and I'm still not sure exactly what you want to accomplish. Are you saying that you specifically want to exclude the word "water" from "water melon" and otherwise output everything as-is, or just output "melon" for *all* kinds of melons, but output other two-word fruit names as they are? It's not clear by what criteria "water melon" becomes "melon", but "green mango" doesn't become "mango". What would you display for "honeydew melon"? Just "melon" or the whole value?

Comment: @AdiInbar, It's ok to ouput everything as it is but I only want "water melon" to output as "melon". If ever I encounter "water melon" it will just output as "melon".

Comment: I think what you want is `SELECT REPLACE(fruit_name, 'water melon', 'melon') AS fruit_name FROM fruits ORDER BY fruit_id`. I can't post an answer while the question is on hold, but I've voted to reopen and will add some explanation.

Comment: BTW, I changed your title to match the question. You don't want to *concatinate* the words, you want to *list* them. Concatinate means join together into one. Concatinated results would be `appleguavayellow mangomeloncacaococonutgreen mango`. It wasn't clear with the original formatting because they were all shown on one line; you need to put lists in code blocks to display them correctly.

Comment: This is getting more and more crazy. What about "watermelon", which is the correct way in English to name the large green fruit with pink insides and black seeds. What about "Ataulfo Mango" - is that listed separately or is it a type of "green mango"? It would help enormously if you could state what rules you want to use to transform your data when you output it.

Comment: @DMac I think he clarified that in his response to my comment: he wants to replace one specific string with another, and output everything else as-is. In the example, "water melon" with "melon", so "watermelon" and "ataulfo mango" would not be changed; and this might be just an illustrative example to convey the concept rather than a practical case anyway. Regardless, he's not trying to apply any sort of categorization scheme, he just wants to replace a specific string with another string, and sort the results according to the value of a different column.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are obviously using a subtle categorization scheme - yellow and green mangos are different but somehow a water melon is just a melon, you need to give your fruit a "category" as well as a name. Then you can select the distinct category to get just the list of categories.

Answer (score 1):

Store the value without the 'water' part.

If that's not an option you can use PHP http://php.net/str_replace or http://www.php.net/explode to remove the first word.

A possible option:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `fruits`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   echo str_replace('water', '', $row[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the values of a given column as they are, except change one specific value with something else, you can use the `REPLACE` function, which applies a simple string replacement:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(fruit_name, 'water melon', 'melon') 
FROM fruits 
ORDER BY fruit_id
```

A few notes:

- `REPLACE(x, y, z)` searches the value of `x` for any occurences of the string `y` and replaces them with the string `z`.
- If you want the results to have the **fruit_name** column heading, you need to add `AS fruit_name` to the end of the first line, because if you're selecting a calculated column (i.e. the results of a function), by default the column in won't have a name. It won't automatically title the column in the results according to the name of the column to which you're applying the function. So, that would be:

  ```sql
  SELECT REPLACE(fruit_name, 'water melon', 'melon') AS fruit_name
  ```
- Your query has `ORDER BY fruit_name`, but that would give you the values of the **fruit_name** field in alphabetical order. According to your example, you want them in the order of the ID. You *can* order by a column that's not part of what you're selecting (e.g. `SELECT column1, column2 FROM table ORDER BY column 3`), so just order by the **fruit_id** column.
- Your query would return no results at all from your sample table. `WHERE column1 NOT IN (<list>)` returns only records where the value of **column1** is not equal to any of the items in the list. Since your list contains all the fruit names, you're excluding everything. If applied to a larger data set, you'd get everything *except* those seven fruit names. So either way, "water melon" wouldn't be in the results at all (nor would apple, guava, yellow mango, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

```
select case fruit_name when 'water melon' then melon else fruit_name end 
from fruits 
order by fruit_id
```